# Android Studio search for occurrences in all projects (including closed ones)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, find

In the process of learning, I want to find pieces of code that I wrote in other projects for reuse in the current project.

How can I find a line in all projects of the working directory (where all my projects are located) even if these projects are not currently open from Android Studio.

I could not find such a feature in the studio itself and in plugins

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a plugin that solve you problem but you can use for sure `grep` on terminal to search for a string in all files in an entire directory

Example:

```
grep -R "val page" .
```

IMHO is not comfortable but it can be useful in extreme cases.